# How to visualize image segmentation results

Tags: neural-network, computer-vision, supervised-learning

I am using u-net to do semantic segmentation for N>1 classes. The input size is (128,128,3), the output size will be (128,128,N). what is the correct way see the prediction as an image ot size n1 x n2 x 1 ?

My try: I took the maximum if every (i,j) vector (of size N) in the output tensor to get an scalar and plot a 128 x 128 image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are saying your model produces a vector of length N for each pixel (holding the *probability* of each class for that pixel), then you are doing the right thing to select the maximum value, of course.

For the plotting, if you leave the image in `128x128`, your output will simply be gray-scale and if you are plotting the raw maximum values you took from each vector, I imagine the image will be very noisy.

You need to map the class of each pixel to a predefined colour mapping. For example, if you have the classes: `tree, car, building, sky`, you should decide on a colour for each of those. For example, specify a dictionary mapping each class to a colour:

```
colour_mappings = {
    'tree': (255, 255, 255)   # white
    'car': (255, 0, 0)        # red
    'building': (0, 255, 0)   # green
    'sky': (0, 0, 255)        # blue
    }
```

No when you have the output matrix of size `128x128`, you can use filtering to replace each of your classified pixels to the colour you put in the mapping above.

### Example

I use the colour mapping above along with a simulated matrix of pixel classification results (for simplicity just 5x5, not 128x128), which is randomly filled with values from `[0, 1, 2, 3]`:

```
classes = array([[0, 3, 3, 1, 0],
                 [2, 2, 0, 3, 2],
                 [3, 1, 0, 0, 1],
                 [1, 3, 2, 2, 2],
                 [1, 3, 1, 2, 1]])
```

Now create an array with three channels, which we will fill based on our results. I just initialise it with zeros, which would be black in colour, which is ok because non of my classes in the mapping above are black (just to avoid confusion):

```
# initialise an empty (black) matrix to hold the image
segmented_image = np.ones((5, 5, 3))          # we require three channel dims for RGB colour
```

Let's say the classes above (in the same order) have the numbers `0, 1, 2, 3` - you could then fill the empty image matrix with the colours as follows.

```
# fill the segmented image based on the class, using your mappings
segmented_image[classes == 0] = colour_mappings['tree']
```

This will produce the following image, where we see all pixels from the class 'tree' now show the mapped colour, white:

[image: first class has been filled. Trees are mapped to white]

Now we can do the same for the remaining classes:

```
segmented_image[classes == 1] = colour_mappings['car']                 
segmented_image[classes == 2] = colour_mappings['building']        
segmented_image[classes == 3] = colour_mappings['sky']
```

This produces the following final image:

[image]

Which can be checked against the `classes` matrix shown above.